# Opening a recordset (rs.openrecordset)

Tags: ms-access, vba

Guys is there any harm in not using rs.openRecordset after a query string in VBA?
I have the following code and I want to know if this will cause any problems.
Since I'm using strSQL3 in strSQL4, do I need to open strSQL3 using e.g. rs.openrecordset?

> ```
>   strSQL3 = "SELECT DISTINCT SUBQUERY1.FullName, SUBQUERY1.FirstNames, SUBQUERY1.Surname, SUBQUERY1.Company, SUBQUERY1.EmailAddress,& _
>         & " SUBQUERY1.In_Email, iif(IsNull([SUBQUERY1].[In_Email]) AND IsNull([SUBQUERY2].[Company]),Null,'Email/Company') AS In_Company" _
>         & " FROM (" & strSQL1 & ") AS SUBQUERY1 LEFT JOIN (" & strSQL2 & ") AS SUBQUERY2 ON SUBQUERY1.Company = SUBQUERY2.Company"
> ```

```
    strSQL4 = "SELECT SUBQUERY3.In_Company" _
     & " FROM (" & strSQL3 & ") AS SUBQUERY3 WHERE (((SUBQUERY3.In_Company)='Email/Company'))"

            Set rs4 = dbs.OpenRecordset(strSQL4)
            rs4.MoveLast
            rs4.MoveFirst
            RsCount = rs4.RecordCount
```

Answer (score 0):

No problem. Openrecordset query data from database as you asked him by SQL string. If you don`t need to access results of strSQL3 in sub you have no need to open rercordset.